# My php project deleted itself after i finished attempting to run it , How can i recover my project?

Tags: php, netbeans

I attempted to run my php file on NETBEANS 8.2 without installing and setting up XAMPP. Internet explorer popped up but an error showed on paged.( i took no notice of the error at the time because i knew XAMPP was not installed.

I then install XAMPP and XDebug correctly before finding out that the php project does not appear in the project explorer (on the left of screen). I search for the files from windows explorer to find that they have been deleted without my knowledge.

There is no code available to show because it is deleted.

I am using Windows 10.
My netbeans supports php 7.0
The project consisted of:

- index.php file containing a homepage (with html code)
- an image file containing various png and jpg files
- a javascript file for slide animation
- a php Header and footer file
- css file
- various empty php files which just include the header and footer php files.

Question 1: What is the probable cause of this phenomenon?
Quesrion 2: How do i prevent it from happening again?
Question 3: Can i recover my php project? How?

Thanks

Comment: It's not much use now, but this is why version control software exists...

Comment: @naththedeveloper Netbeans use version control by default so this should not happen ...

Comment: Should the source folder for php.files  be located  in: xammp/htdocs. or should i have changed the default location to the netbeans projects folder, where my html projects reside. if so i think i may have had a xampp folder lingering around which was  where my files would have been located. When i installed xampp control panel, it must have deleted an old  xampp folder.